# How to make auto horizontal scroll in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, react-hooks, css-transitions

I am working on one small thing where I have to make my divs (card) scroll horizontally with animation kind of without any button click.

**What I am trying to achieve**

- I have some data of countries, which I am looping and showing horizontally on screen
- I am using flex display to show them, and when scroll giving overflow scroll as hidden and using below code to do the automatic scroll

My component and the function to scroll are below:

```
const useAnimationFrame = (callback) => {
    const requestRef = useRef();

    const animate = () => {
      callback();
      requestRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    };
    useEffect(() => {
      requestRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      return () => cancelAnimationFrame(requestRef.current);
    }, []);
   };

   function Bubble({ Name, className}) {
    const [position, setPosition] = useState(0);
    console.log(CANVAS_WIDTH);
    useAnimationFrame(() =>
      setPosition((prevPosition) => {
        const newPosition = prevPosition - SCROLL_SPEED;

        return newPosition < -200 ? CANVAS_WIDTH : newPosition;
      })
    );
   return (
    <div
    style={{
      transform: `translate(${position}px, 20px)`,
    }}
    className=""
    >
    <div className="card m-2 pt-2">
      <div className="py-1">
        <div className="fs-5 mt-2">{Name}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 );
}
```

So in above code I have given initial position as 0, but the code I am following are taking it from data

Actually my use case is little different:

- I am almost done with the code, but the thing is it is not scrolling properly as I think I have made some issue with `transform` or the CSS
- below I am including both code sandboxes of what I have done and what I resource I am following

[This is what I have done till now](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-babycat-k77sne?file=/src/App.js)

[This is what I am following for help](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-liskov-4vbfq?file=/src/constants.js)

I am okay with any other approach with CSS or with react-hooks, I am looking for the best approach here which will helpful for future as well.

**Edit / update**

- I have updated two code sandbox, The first one is How I am trying to do
- I have card and showing it horizontally using d-flex in row
- Now there are lot of cards so there are in form of scroll, Want to show that scroll automatically, do not want to scroll on click

**The other code sand box**

- This one I found an example on google which I am using for my help, they are showing in form of bubbles which is not my case but I am using there approach
- Now just stuck with scroll

**Please see both the code sandbox example for better understanding**

I am open to any other approach, be it totaly with CSS or mixture of css and JS in react.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have switched from javaScript animations to css animations.
App.js:

```
import { useRef, useEffect, useState, useLayoutEffect } from "react";
import Card from "./Card.js";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const [containerWidth, setWidth] = useState(100 + "%");
  const [animationState, setPlay] = useState("paused");
  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      setWidth(ref.current.scrollWidth + "px");
      setPlay("running");
    }
  }, []);
  const renderCards = data.map((el, index) => {
    return <Card key={index} cardName={el.Name} />;
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div
        className="d-flex"
        ref={ref}
        style={{
          width: `${containerWidth}`,
          animationPlayState: animationState
        }}
      >
        {renderCards}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Created another component for cards.
Card.js:

```
import { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
export default function Card({ cardName, refCard }) {
  return (
    <div className="bubble">
      <div className="card m-2 pt-2">
        <div className="py-1">
          <div className="fs-5 mt-2">{cardName}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And for css i used keyframes and translateX. Animation starts from right and ends on  the left. In order to make d-flex translateX(-100%) of its exact width with keyframes i set its offsetWidth to its scrollWidth.

```
.App {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.card {
  width: 200px !important;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 1px rgba(158, 151, 151, 0.25);
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin: 12px;
  padding: 12px;
}
.d-flex {
  display: flex;
  transform: translateX(calc(100vw));
  overflow: visible;
  animation: animateContainer 10s linear forwards infinite;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
@keyframes animateContainer {
  from {
    transform: translateX(calc(100vw));
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(calc(-100%));
  }
}
```

[codesandbox.io link](https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-sound-c9w9b1)

Comment: I check your sand box, there are several issue, first of all I don't want to show it in bubbles, I am showing in cards and linear  you can check my code sandbox what I have done, the other sandbox is just an example I am following.In your case it is like bubbles one over other and some are going fast some slow

Comment: Can you check this out and tell me if this is what you are looking for. [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-joji-xkpngh?file=/src/styles.css)

Comment: I am trying to build something like this only, but please have a look it doesn't scroll fully, it is scrolling till middle and again starting from start, it should be start from india go till Egypt and again start from India scroll till Egypt, in your case it is not going till Egypt, it is going somewhere in middle and then starting over again.

Comment: Alright if you don't want the first element to show right after the last one [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-brattain-su19f9?file=/src/App.js) works. If you want a continuous animation where the first element starts again right after the last one it needs a little bit more work.

Comment: I can see you are using styled component, is it required ? if yes can you please explain me the use case of this here.

Comment: Well in order to do this animation with css i have to set keywords. With the keywords i set translateX property to negative of its exact width so when the animation ends it cannot be seen. The problem with css starts here because when i set percetange values to this it does not consider scrollWidth of the element. In order to access scrollWidth property of the element i have to use javaScript and in order to edit the keyframes with javascript i used the styled components. If you can find another way other than styled componenets to set keyframes values you can use it aswell.

Comment: This works fine, but I think this styled component is making it bit complicated, also we should call styled outside the render method, but here we can not.

Comment: I believe i found a way around styled component. Changed the logic of setting keyframe to setting the offsetWidth of the element to scrollWidth. This way percentage value in keyframes still have acces to the scrollWidth. [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-sound-c9w9b1?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Yes this looks totally Fine, you can update your answer.

Comment: Hi I just got one thing, when the last dive is done there is spacing between them can we do it more in circular way so when there is last it should start from there only no gap, it would be great if you help

Comment: I tried to find a solution but i think without editing the keyframes it is not achievable with this approach without making it overcomplicated. If i find a solution i will let you know.

Comment: ya please let me know, when you find a solution.

Comment: Well instead of using styled components i created another component to inject keyframes. If you are using a static data just edit the css or just keep using the component. Here you go [infinite loop](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-aryabhata-rgr2wo?file=/src/styles.css)

Comment: I just saw one thing, why you are writing `{renderCards}` twice ? could you please explain me.

Comment: I am creating the same div twice to create the illusion of infinite loop. What really happens during the animation is the second {renderCards} are filling the gap between the animation on the first example. When the animation ends, the first elements are positioned on top of the second {renderCards] to create the illusion. I used this method to ensure that this works on every single device as long as the length of d-flex is bigger than the viewport. You can see this by observing the first card of the second {renderCards} and see its behavior.

Comment: ohh i see, but is it the correct way I mean will it cause any performance issue, if I have 200 cards or 100.

Comment: You can remove the second {renderCards} if you assign the cards with to some percantage of the window width. With this you can always know when to restart the animation with js. But controling the elements with js will cause further performance issues. What you can do is limit the second {renderCards} to only to fill the viewport. Lets say if the cards have 200px width and the viewport has 1600px, only render the first 8 cards on the second {renderCards}.

Comment: Can you please share one example for this

Comment: Also, with your https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-aryabhata-rgr2wo?file=/src/App.js this, if I am limiting the data, lets say to only four then the scroll time is very slow, so I think it is depending on data for the scroll time, I don't want the scroll to be dependent on data, data can be less or more, it will come from an api or from a json file, which can have 10 data or 20 or more.

Comment: Check this [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-aryabhata-rgr2wo?file=/src/App.js). Change the speed ratio to your liking. It should always maintain the same speed no matter the viewport width or the data length. Keep in mind that don't add any paddings or margins to d-flex since i am using cardWidth to determine its scrollWidth with the current code.